# Extract top positive and negative features when applying dictionary in quanteda

Tags: r, dictionary, sentiment-analysis, quanteda

I have a data frame with around 100k rows that contain textual data. Using the quanteda package, I apply sentiment analysis (Lexicoder dictionary) to eventually calculate a sentiment score. 
For an additional - more qualitative - step of analysis I would like extract the top features (i.e. negative/positive words from the dictionary that occur most frequent in my data) to examine whether the discourse is driven by particular words.

```
my_corpus <- corpus(my_df, docid_field = "ID", text_field = "my_text", metacorpus = NULL, compress = FALSE)
sentiment_corp <- dfm(my_corpus, dictionary = data_dictionary_LSD2015)
```

However, going through the [quanteda documentation](https://quanteda.io/), I couldn't figure out how to achieve this - is there a way? 
I'm aware of `topfeatures` and I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746362/quanteda-extracting-identified-dictionary-words), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all of the **quanteda** functions that take a `pattern` argument, the valid types of patterns are character vectors, lists, and dictionaries.  So the best way to assess each the top features in each dictionary category (what we also call a dictionary *key*) is to select on that dictionary and then use `topfeatures()`.

Here is how to do this using the built-in `data_corpus_irishbudget2010` object, as an example, with the Lexicoder Sentiment Dictionary.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3

# tokenize and select just the dictionary value matches
toks <- tokens(data_corpus_irishbudget2010) %>%
  tokens_select(pattern = data_dictionary_LSD2015)
lapply(toks[1:5], head)
## $`Lenihan, Brian (FF)`
## [1] "severe"        "distress"      "difficulties"  "recovery"     
## [5] "benefit"       "understanding"
## 
## $`Bruton, Richard (FG)`
## [1] "failed"   "warnings" "sucking"  "losses"   "debt"     "hurt"    
## 
## $`Burton, Joan (LAB)`
## [1] "remarkable" "consensus"  "Ireland"    "opposition" "knife"     
## [6] "dispute"   
## 
## $`Morgan, Arthur (SF)`
## [1] "worst"     "worst"     "well"      "corrupt"   "golden"    "protected"
## 
## $`Cowen, Brian (FF)`
## [1] "challenge"      "succeeding"     "challenge"      "oppose"        
## [5] "responsibility" "support"
```

To explore the top matches for the positive entry, we can select them further by subsetting the dictionary for the Positive key.

```r
# top positive matches
tokens_select(toks, pattern = data_dictionary_LSD2015["positive"]) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  topfeatures()
##    benefit    support   recovery       fair     create confidence 
##         68         52         44         41         39         37 
##    provide       well     credit       help 
##         36         33         31         29
```

And for Negative:

```r
# top negative matches
tokens_select(toks, pattern = data_dictionary_LSD2015[["negative"]]) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  topfeatures()
##    ireland    benefit        not    support     crisis   recovery 
##         79         68         52         52         47         44 
##       fair     create    deficit confidence 
##         41         39         38         37
```

Why is "Ireland" a negative match?  Because the LSD2015 includes `ir*` as a negative word that is intended to match *ire* and *ireful* but with the default case insensitive matching, also matches *Ireland* (a term frequently used in this example corpus).  This is an example of a "false positive" match, always a risk in dictionaries when using wildcarding or when using a language such as English that has a very high rate of polysemes and homographs.